# React native custom webview prevent SSL errors while developing

Tags: android, react-native, ssl, react-native-webview

**Issue**
Trying to connect to my local development server using `react-native-webview` on Android.
You can use `http://10.0.0.2` as the default gateway to connect to your local machine on the emulator. Alternatively, I ran the build on my phone and connected to the IPV4 address of my machine.
I need the [Crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto) API and that's only available on HTTPS, which meant I needed to connect to `https://10.0.0.2`.
I didn't get the self signed certificate to work.

**Quick & dirty solution**
Call `handler.proceed()` on the first line of the `onReceivedSslError` method of the `com.reactnativecommunity.webview` package.
Although this might work, it's not the preferred way because it's not under source control and needs to be removed each time a release build is made or the project is freshly installed.

**Solution**
*See answers below*
Create a custom webview on development builds to circumvent the SSL error (or any other webview method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution**

**1.** Create a debug only class `CustomWebviewManager.java`
*We don't want our custom webview manager ending up in release builds.*

```
package nl.myapp;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.net.http.SslError;

import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewManager;

@ReactModule(name = CustomWebViewManager.REACT_CLASS)
public class CustomWebViewManager extends RNCWebViewManager {
    protected static final String REACT_CLASS = "RNCCustomWebView"; // React native import name

    protected static class CustomWebviewClient extends RNCWebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){
            // Prevent SSL errors
            handler.proceed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected void addEventEmitters(ThemedReactContext reactContext, WebView view) {
        // Set our custom client as webview client
        view.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebviewClient());
    }
}
```

**2.** Create a new class to register React Packages `MyappAppPackage.java`
*We should register our debug class only on debug mode and as a `ViewManager`.*
*React Native will call `createViewManagers` automatically after registering our package in the next step*
*Use `BuildConfig.DEBUG` to only execute in debug builds.*
*We cannot instantiate our class directly, as it will cause errors in productions builds. That's why we use `Class.forName`*

```
package nl.myapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyappAppPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<ViewManager> viewManagers = new ArrayList<>();

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            // Add custom webview manager to circumvent SSL errors
            try {
                Class<ViewManager> c = (Class<ViewManager>) Class.forName("nl.myapp.CustomWebViewManager");
                viewManagers.add(c.newInstance());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return viewManagers;
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

**3.** Register our package

```
package nl.myapp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
        new ReactNativeHost(this) {
          @Override
          public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
              return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
          }

          @Override
          protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
              @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
              List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();

              packages.add(new MyappAppPackage());

              return packages;
          }

          @Override
          protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
              return "index";
          }
        };

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }

    ...
}
```

**4.** And finally use our custom webview while developing
*Put it in separate file, otherwise hot-reloading won't work because `requireNativeComponent` would try to register the `ViewManager` again*
*`src/components/native/RNCCustomWebView.js`*

```
import {requireNativeComponent} from 'react-native';

module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RNCCustomWebView');
```

*`src/components/webview.js`*

```
import React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import RNCCustomWebView from './native/RNCCustomWebView';

// ...

const renderWebView = () => {
  // ...

  const nativeConfig = {};
  if (__DEV__) { // __DEV__ is set by RN on debug builds
    // Set custom component to circumvent SSL errors
    nativeConfig.component = RNCCustomWebView;
  }

  return (
    <WebView
      nativeConfig={nativeConfig}
      source="https://10.0.0.1"
    />
  );
};
```